# Is REST API that accepts nested object as params recommended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api

I am developing a restful API. My create Reservation method requires parameters like data, location etc. It also requires a list of People. Those people have name, birthdate etc.

So to pass the people to the API I need to send a nested object to the API. This is something that I usually don't see out there in the API world.

So my question is: Are there any problems with this and should I somehow flatten the parameter object or is it no problem at all to accept a nested object as parameter?

Comment: I see this all the time. APIs take what they take-if they need a collection they need a collection. The argument against it would be that you actually have two endpoints: one to create the resource, and one to add each of its child resources.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no problems with this but usually its not preferable because consumer of API need to understand the nested JSON and construct while calling. API having simple request JSON and syntax is always preferable.

Answer (score 0):

This type of strategy is totally linked to modeling and coupling with the information-producing system.

In my opnion, if the resources can be structured sequentially as child resources, in this way the navigation and resuabilidad becomes more interesting. To minimize the number of calls a design pattern [API Gateway with agragation](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) is being pretty much in today by corporations.

Example:

- POST http://api.teste.com/clients/ --> This is going to create a new client resource and returning the new client identification
- POST http://api.teste.com/clients/1/addresses